# Cannot create new Rust project with Docker: "could not determine the current user"

Tags: docker, rust

Following the [Docker documentation for Rust](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust/), I can't create a new project using `cargo new` without getting `could not determine the current user, please set $USER`. Here's the command I'm using:

```sh
docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/app -w /app rust:1.27.0-slim-stretch cargo new project --bin
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Forwarding the `$USER` environment variable from my machine seems to do the trick:

```sh
docker run -it --rm -e USER=$USER -v "$PWD":/app -w /app rust:1.27.0-slim-stretch cargo new project --bin
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to fix this inside the container, run:
`$ export USER=yourname`